# error: error parsing helm/templates/config-map.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: could not find expected ':'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using the config map and giving the data input as JSON and did the deployment, everything looks good. (able to see the configmaps inside my POD )

I tried to update the config map without restarting the POD ( it gets updated only if i am passing the data value as properties, not as JSON file).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-schooltest-app
data:
  config_dev.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "conf/config_dev.json" | indent 4}}
  config_qa.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "conf/config_qa.json" | indent 4}}
```

kubectl apply -f helm/templates/config-map.yaml

error: error parsing helm/templates/config-map.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: could not find expected ':'

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "proffesion": "Engineer",
      "subjectCodes": [
        "SOCIAL",
        "SCIENCE",
        "MATHS"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "proffesion": "Engineer",
      "subjectCodes": [
        "ENGLISH",
        "TAMIL"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "allowedSubjects": [
    "SOCIAL",
    "SCIENCE",
    "MATHS",
    "ENGLISH",
    "TAMIL"
  ],
  "school": "trm",
  "headmaster": [
    "Test5"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can't use `kubectl apply` with files with Helm templating; you need to use tools like `helm upgrade` to apply a modified configuration.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the update, but the helm upgrade always to do the pod restart right? I want to update the config map without restarting the POD https://v3.helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: `helm upgrade` will send the Deployment spec to the cluster, but if the Deployment `template:` is unchanged then it won't recreate its Pods.  (You probably shouldn't have bare Pod objects in your Helm chart; use a higher-level object instead.)